# Banach-Bundle: What is differentiability on "only" topological space?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I have a question concerning the definition given in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_bundle#Definition_of_a_Banach_bundle). There, a banach-bundle is defined. My question refers to the second bullet point. There, the map $\tau_{ij}: U_i \cap U_j \to \text{Lin}(X_i,X_j)$ has to be a differentiable map of $C^p$. But the $U_i$ and $U_j$ are just open subsets of the banach-manifold $X$. As far as I know, we only get that $X$ is a topological space, not however a normed vector space. So, how can the map $\tau_{ij}$ be a differential map if the domain is not a normed vector space? Is there some way to identify $U_i \cap U_j$ with a normed vector space? Or do we talk about some other differentiability?

Comment: Consider reading S.Lang "Differential manifolds" where he defines these things for general Banach manifolds. As for your title question, it is different from the one in the body of the question (which is never a good idea) and, of course, differentiability in this generality makes no sense.